# Count lines between "X"s

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to count the lines between "X"s. This is just an example; I have to apply the code to a complex biological result. I will be thankful if you can suggest some command, preferably using `awk`, `grep` or `sed` as I am familiar with those.

Example:

```
X
Y
Y
Y
X
Y
Y
Y
Y
X
Y
X
```

Desired Output:

```
3
4
1
```

Comment: You might be interested in [bioinformatics.se] if you'll be working in this field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '!/X/{count++}/X/{print count; count = 0}' input

3
4
1
```

Increment a count for every line not containing `X`; print and reset the count for lines containing `X`.

Comment: If the first line was not an `X`, the first number of lines would still be counted and outputted with this solution, until the first line with `X` is matched. EX (Can't add new lines in comments, but consider there's a new line between each character ;P): `Y X Y Y X Y Y Y` would output: `1 2`

Comment: @muru this will not work if there was no X at end (need add `END{if (count)print count}`), and producing empty line where X was in start to avoid you can add `/X/&&count` in condition also

Comment: Heh. One comment complains that leading `Y`s shouldn't be counted because they're not exactly between two `X`s; the other complains that trailing `Y`s aren't counted because they're not exactly between two `X`s. I'll wait for the OP to clarify, if needed; I'm fine with this answer as it is until then.

Answer (score 12):

```
$ awk '/X/ && prev{print NR-prev-1} /X/{prev=NR}' file
3
4
1
```

How it works:

Awk implicitly reads through input files line by line.

- `/X/ && prev{print NR-prev-1}`

  For any line that contains `X` and if we have previously assigned a value to `prev`, then print out the number of the current line, `NR`, minus `prev` minus one.
- `/X/{prev=NR}`

  For any line that contains `X`, set the variable `prev` to the current line number, `NR`.

Comment: Huh, nice. Abusing `NR` gives me an idea: `awk '/X/{print NR - 1; NR = 0}' foo`

Comment: Thank you, It gives me the exact info. which is required.

Comment: Muro: Nice & tricky.  Except for printing one value too many, it works for me under gawk and mawk.  I'm curious as to whether this is guaranteed behavior. @EdMorton?

Comment: @rhea Unless your first line is always an `X`, there is a small difference in the output between the 2 answers as I explained in a comment under muru's answer.

Comment: I am a biologist and want to become pro in coding i know the basics and I am working on linux from a long time but still I am not able to make code by myself can  you guys suggest me any tutorial or something which can help me.

Comment: @Rhea To start, [Grymoire has a good awk tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).  For advanced study of awk, consider Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: @John1024 thankyou! I hope it will help me.

Comment: @John1024 if there was no X at first it will ignore counting and print; + if there was no X at end will ignore counting and print

Comment: @muru: I don't like it but it's clever ^^  But maybe use FNR instead of NR as otherwise you may count lines between "last X in previous file and first X in current one" ? And I think this may have lots of other problems (messing with FNR/NR seems wrong, imo : maybe awk enters some sort of "undefined" state where anything could happen)

Answer (score 6):

Another simple `awk` approach which works on OP's sample data [and if `X` was not in first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953821/count-lines-between-x#comment1520464_953823) or even in last or repeated Xs.

```
awk -v RS='X' 'NF{print NF}' infile
```

Above is correct when there is only one field in each line with default FS any *whitespaces*, otherwise below is revised in general case for counting *linewise*. You can input your ***PATTERN*** in place of ***X*** there.

```
awk -F'\n' -v RS='X' 'NF>2{print NF-2}'
```

Sample input:

```
X
Y YYY Y
YY
YY Y YY YY Y Y
X
Y Y Y
X
Y
Y
X
X
```

The output is:

```
3
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers here match the content of the line to be counted using regular expressions embedded into the Awk program. If you need to match lines with content that may contain special characters (either to Awk or regular expressions) it would be better to actually compare strings for equality. Therefore I propose the following Awk script as a variant of [muru’s answer](/a/953823/175814):

```awk
BEGIN {
    count = 0;
}

{
    if ($0 == needle) {
        if (count) {
            print count;
            count = 0;
        }
    } else {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Store it as a text file, e. g. `count-rows.awk`, and invoke it as follows:

```
awk -f count-rows.awk -v needle=X input
```

You can adjust the value of `needle` to your liking. The advantage of this method is that you can invoke the program from a shell script with an arbitrary value for `needle` without escaping issues:

```sh
awk -f count-rows.awk -v needle="$needle" input
```